# Netlogo: how to get the path from which a model runs

Tags: path, netlogo

another likely silly question from me, but I have searched everywhere in vain.

Assume I have a netlogo model in the folder 'C:\Temp\NLmodel'. I go to this folder and run the model. I would like netlogo to generate the string 'C:\Temp\NLmodel' (that is the output the path of where it is running from) which I can then write to an output file.

is there a way to do so?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pathdir extension will give you that information, as well as some other useful directory stuff.  NetLogo will load the extension for you if you put it in your extension list.  Here is the direct link.

https://github.com/cstaelin/Pathdir-Extension

Charles

Comment: sorry for replying so late, i was on extended leave. Your suggestion works perfectly